# Add values in the components embedded multi-value field using core service API's

Tags: core-service

I'm trying to add values in the components field using core service API's.Component have embedded field with multi-value.when i am trying to add field value it is updating first field value and not adding new field.
code sample is as follows:

```
        var schemaFields = client.ReadSchemaFields("tcm:1030-19313-8", true, new ReadOptions());

        // load a component based on that schema
        var component = (ComponentData)client.Read("tcm:1030-19314", new ReadOptions());

        //Console.WriteLine(component.Content);

        // build a magical Fields object from it
        var fields = Fields.ForContentOf(schemaFields, component);

        // let's first quickly list all values of all fields
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            if (field.Type == typeof(EmbeddedSchemaFieldDefinitionData))
            {
               Fields embededFields = fields[field.Name].GetSubFields();

               embededFields["SourceID"].Value = "vcvcv";
               embededFields["TargetTCMID"].Value = "vcvcv";

             }
        }

        FullVersionInfo itemInfo = null;
        itemInfo = (FullVersionInfo)component.VersionInfo;
        if (itemInfo.LockType.Value != LockType.CheckedOut)
        {
            client.CheckOut("tcm:1030-19314", true, new ReadOptions());
            component.Content = fields.ToString();
            client.Save(component, new ReadOptions());
            client.CheckIn("tcm:1030-19314", new ReadOptions());
        }
```

Schema is as follows:

It has only one embedded field Mapping and Mapping have two text fields SourceID,TargetTCMID

I tried AddValues() also

Actually I am new to Core Service Concept...can you please help me on this issue...

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the AddValue() function is what you are looking for.

I didn't test this code, but I think this should help you to add new fields

```
foreach (var field in fields)
{
   if (field.Type == typeof(EmbeddedSchemaFieldDefinitionData))
   {
      fields[field.Name].AddValue();
      Fields embededFields = fields[field.Name].SubFields.Last();
      embededFields["SourceID"].Value = "vcvcv";
      embededFields["TargetTCMID"].Value = "vcvcv";
   }
}
```

This code will do the following

- if your field is an embedded schema field, it will add a new value to the fields
- it will then get the last value of the embedded fields (the empty one you just added)
- it will then fill out the proper values of your empty embedded schema fields

If you need to add multiple values, just repeat this code.

Comment: Great to hear. Can you set this answer as an accepted answer then. That way, it might help others who have the same problem/question